# Python - How to include any random integer in a string

Tags: python, sockets, random, xmpp, ejabberd

I have created a ban bot for an XMPP server, this is a part of my script:

```
resources = ['private', 'sergeant', 'staffsergeant']

"""presence detection script here"""
if resource in resources:
    pass
else:
    print "the jid has been banned"
    """ban script here"""
```

So the code above bans any user that enters unless their resource is `private`, `sergeant` or `staffsergeant`.

I want to change the above script to **not** ban any of the above resources if and only if they have an integer after the resource name (for example: `sergeant343`, `private5654`, etc.), but to ban them if they come without any integer. So `jid/sergeant` gets banned but `jid/sergeant432` passes. The integer could be any number in `range(0, 99999)`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution looks like this:

```
if resource.rstrip('0123456789') in resources:
    if resource != resource.rstrip('0123456789'):
        print 'ok'
    else:
        print 'banned'
else:
    raise NotImplementedError()  # replace with own code
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression.

```
if not re.match(u'^(' + u'|'.join(resources) + u')\d+$', string):
  # Ban here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import random as rn

my_string = 'string'

new_string = my_string + str(rn.randint(0,99999))
```

Result:

```
>>> new_string
'string32566'
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want done with things like `sergeant00432`?

How about something like this?

```
allowed_prefixes = ['private', 'sergeant', 'staffsergeant']

def resource_is_allowed(r):
    for prefix in allowed_prefixes:
        if re.match(prefix + '[0-9]{,5}', r):
            return True
    return False
```

or, more concisely but maybe less clearly,

```
def resource_is_allowed(r):
    return any(re.match(prefix + '[0-9]{,5}', r) for prefix in allowed_prefixes)
```

Note that these treat the prefixes as regular expressions. The particular prefixes you've specified have the same meaning as REs as they do as plain strings; if you might start having allowed resource prefixes containing characters with special meanings in REs then more caution would be necessary.